# Is there any way to close the live streaming from a host (even if there are multiple hosts exist)?

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

Assume multiple hosts are contributing to a stream. If one of the speaker/host closes/exits from the stream. The stream should be closed for all the speakers. Is there any way to achieve this in agora web sdk ng?

Comment: Are you using Audio/View Call or Live Interactive Audio/Video Streaming?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Agora's Real Time Messaging](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/index.html) to send a message to all hosts asking to end the stream and once that particular message is received, you can call the close stream function for all speakers, hosts and audience.